# Update not working properly in sqlite database while programming for android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am actually a beginner in android programming. When I try to update my database it does not update.
I can't find the error myself. Please help me!!!
 This is my code:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.text.style.UpdateAppearance;



public class Inventorydb{
public static final String KEY_name = "persons_firstname";
public static final String KEY_id = "dob";
public static final String KEY_price = "price";
public static final String KEY_quan = "quan";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotorNo.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopletable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper OurHelper;
private Context OurContext;
private SQLiteDatabase OurDatabase;

public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "( " +
                // KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT," +
                KEY_name + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_id + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                KEY_price + " TEXT, "+
                KEY_quan + " TEXT,"+
                " PRIMARY KEY( " + KEY_id + " )" +
                " ) ;"
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Inventorydb(Context c) {
    OurContext = c ;
}

public Inventorydb open() throws SQLException{
    OurHelper = new DbHelper(OurContext);
    OurDatabase = OurHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    OurHelper.close();
   }

    public long createEntry(String name, String date,String d,String g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    name = name.trim();
    date = date.trim();
    d=d.trim();
    g=g.trim();
    if(!name.contentEquals(""))
    cv.put(KEY_name, name);

    if(!date.contentEquals(""))
    cv.put(KEY_id, date);

    cv.put(KEY_price, d);
    cv.put(KEY_quan, g);

    return OurDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }

    public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String result = " ";

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_name, KEY_id,KEY_price,KEY_quan};

    Cursor c = OurDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c==null)
        return result;

    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_name);
    // int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iD = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_id);
    int ip=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_price);
    int iq=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_quan);
    for( c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast() ; c.moveToNext() )
    {
        result = result + c.getString(iName) + "\t" +
                c.getString(iD) + "\t"+c.getString(ip)+"\t"+c.getString(iq)+"\t"+"\n" ;
    }

    return result;
}
public String getprice(String iid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_id,KEY_name,KEY_price,KEY_quan};
    iid=iid.trim();
    String price,quantity,temp="";
    Cursor c=OurDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null){
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
             temp=c.getString(1);
            if(temp.contains(iid)){
              price=c.getString(2);
              return price;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String getquan(String iid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_id,KEY_name,KEY_price,KEY_quan};
    iid=iid.trim();
    String quantity,temp="";
    Cursor c=OurDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null){
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
             temp=c.getString(1);
            if(temp.contains(iid)){
              quantity=c.getString(3);
              return quantity;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String getname(String iid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_id,KEY_name,KEY_price,KEY_quan};
    iid=iid.trim();
    String quantity,temp="";
    Cursor c=OurDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null){
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
             temp=c.getString(1);
            if(temp.contains(iid)){
              quantity=c.getString(0);
              return quantity;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

 public void updatetable(String l, String price, String name, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvup=new ContentValues();
    cvup.put(KEY_id, l);
    cvup.put(KEY_name, name);
    cvup.put(KEY_price, price);
    cvup.put(KEY_quan, i);
    OurDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup,  KEY_quan  + "=" + l, null);
 }
}
```

Here's my Activity class that uses this java code:

```
   public class Userdata extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
   EditText id,total,number;
   Button another;
    int result=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.userdata);
    id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etid);
    number=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etnoofitem);
    total=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etamount);
    another=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addanother);
    another.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.addanother:String iid,nofitems;
    iid=id.getText().toString();
    nofitems=number.getText().toString();
    Inventorydb entry=new Inventorydb(this);
    entry.open();
    String price=entry.getprice(iid);
    String quantity=entry.getquan(iid);
    int t=Integer.parseInt(quantity);
    String name=entry.getname(iid);
    int q=Integer.parseInt(nofitems);
    long l=Long.parseLong(iid);
    int h=t-q;
    entry.updatetable(iid,price,name,h);
    entry.close();
    int p=Integer.parseInt(price);

    int temp=p*q;
    result=result+temp;
    total.setText(" "+result  );
    id.setText("");
    number.setText("");
    }

  }
}
```

I am creating an inventory database for my mini project. I have already tried using execsql and rawquery statements, but those are also not working. I think there is something I'm not understanding properly.

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: I am not getting any errors neither exceptions .but i won't update.if i use execSql statements my app crashes

Comment: Are you sure you understand the expected behavior properly? If I understand correctly, the `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)` method will be called when your database version needs to be updated. But you don't mention anything about this, and I see you define your database version as `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;`. The `onUpgrade()` code is only run when you've already constructed a DB with version 1, and then you update the version and run it again (like when a user updates your app to a newer version).

Answer (score 0):

```java
OurDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup,  KEY_quan  + "=" + l, null);
```

The ID column is named by `KEY_id`.
Furthermore, string values must be quoted inside SQL, or better given as parameters:

```java
OurDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup, KEY_d + "=?", new String[]{l});
```

Comment: Still the same .Not updating

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted will update all records where the 'KEY_quan' field is equal to the 'l' parameter which is actually KEY_id. There may be no records (or multiple records) that match this condition.

You should change the 'whereClause' parameter in your call to SQLiteDatabase.update to identify a single existing record based on 'KEY_id' instead of 'KEY_quan'.

Do you really want to update the primary key?

If not, you should save the ID field in a variable or non-editable TextView and then rewrite the 'updatetable' function like this:

```
public void updatetable(String l, String price, String name, int i) {
    ContentValues cvup=new ContentValues();
    cvup.put(KEY_name, name);
    cvup.put(KEY_price, price);
    cvup.put(KEY_quan, i);
    OurDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup,  KEY_id  + "=?", new String[]{l});
 }
```

If so, you should save the original ID field in a variable and then rewrite the 'updatetable' function like this:

```
public void updatetable(String oldId, String newId, String price, String name, int i) {
    ContentValues cvup=new ContentValues();
    cvup.put(KEY_id, newId);
    cvup.put(KEY_name, name);
    cvup.put(KEY_price, price);
    cvup.put(KEY_quan, i);
    OurDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup,  KEY_id  + "=?", new String[]{oldId});
 }
```

If you only want to update the KEY_quan field:

```
public void updateQuantity(String iid, int quan) {
        ContentValues cvup=new ContentValues();
        cvup.put(KEY_quan, quan);
        OurDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup,  KEY_id  + "=?", new String[]{iid});
     }
```

As a side note, when you want to retrieve values you should again identify which record you want instead of looping through the entire table.

```
public String getquan(String iid) {
        Cursor c=OurDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_quan}, KEY_id+"=?", new String[]{iid}, null, null, null);
        try {
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c.getString(0);
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to update the value of KEY_quan i.e the value of i

Comment: If that's the only field you want to update then you should only add that one field to the ContentValues. Either way you still need to identify an existing record with the 'whereClause' parameter.

Answer (score -1):

This happens sometimes with SQLite database, it does not recognize the updates you made, just change the name of your db like,
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotorNoabc.db"
and then run your app.